# How to define a RestResource method that accepts both HttpGet and httpPost

Tags: apex, restresource

I've setup a RestResource that receives a webhook from Mailchimp.
When setting up the webhook in Mailchimp it verifies the webhook URL exists by calling it with a GET Method but then sends all future requests as POST Methods.

How can I setup my rest resource to handle a Get and Post on the same method while avoiding the Method already defined error?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mailchimp/*')
global without sharing class RestMailchimpWebhook {

    @HttpPost
    global static void callbacks(){
       ... // handle webhooks
    }

    @HttpGet
    global static void callbacks(){
       ... //handle verification
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two methods with the exact same names and parameters in the same class. Just change the names, you'll be fine. The general convention I've seen is `doX`, where `X` is the HTTP verb.

```
@HttpPost
global static void doPost(){
   ... // handle webhooks
}

@HttpGet
global static void doGet(){
   ... //handle verification
}
```

You can, however, choose whatever name you want to that's a valid method name.

The name of the method has nothing to do with the wildcard in the `urlMapping` attribute in `@RestResource`. You would want to specify the URL you're trying to handle in the `urlMapping` property itself.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/mailchimp/callbacks')
```

Comment: Ahh, the issue was I've been using the urlMapping with a star. But by changing it to ```@RestResource(urlMapping='/mailchimp/callbacks')``` it will automatically route to doGet and doPost. Perhaps update the answer to include @RestResource for clarity and I'll accept. Thanks!!

Comment: @Dan Sure thing.